# Filtering a Django queryset once a slice has been taken

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In a django forum I maintain, I hell-ban users who're abusive, for 4 days. In the "Home page" of the forum, I display everyones comments, but exclude comments by people who're hell-banned. It goes like this:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user_banned: #if user is hell-banned
            return Link.objects.order_by('-id')[:120]
        else: #if user is not hell-banned
            global condemned
            queryset = Link.objects.order_by('-id').exclude(submitter_id__in=condemned)[:120]
            return queryset
```

The above is a `get_queryset` method of a `ListView`. Notice how hell-banned users can't tell their comments are being excluded from the site (the point of the hell ban). `condemned` is a list containing primary keys of hell-banned users.

Now I want to optimize the above by *slicing first and excluding banned people later*. I'm trying to do that via:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user_banned: #if user is hell-banned
        return Link.objects.order_by('-id')[:120]
    else: #if user is not hell-banned
        global condemned
        queryset = Link.objects.order_by('-id')[:120]
        queryset = queryset.exclude(submitter_id__in=condemned)
        return queryset
```

This unfotunately gives me the error:

> Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

What alternatives do I have? Need the most efficient solution I can find, since performance is key. I'm on Django < 1.8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Django version specifically?  Django < 1.8  is unnecessarily vague ..

Comment: How long is the query taking? Why do you think that 'slicing first and excluding banned people later' will be quicker? Is `submitter_id` a foreign key? How big is the `condemned` list?

Comment: Yep, `submitter_id` is a foreign key, and the `condemned` list grows to a few hundred objects. I'll properly benchmark it and get back to you with the time, but tell me something, if I *slice* first, and then *exclude*, wouldn't I just be iterating through 120 objects (whereas in the other case, I go through the whole object_list, exclude condemned ids everywhere, and then slice)?

Comment: Cool, just post that in the reply and it would suffice.

Comment: def get_queryset(self, request):
        limited_ids = Items.objects.order_by("-id").values_list("id", flat=True)[:3]
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).filter(id__in=limited_ids)
        return qs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Django doesn't let you filter after a slice, because in the underlying SQL, you can't easily `limit` the results and then filter with `where`.

Doing the filtering then the slice probably not a problem anyway. Note that [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), so Django will only ever fetch 120 objects from the db.

You'll need to do some benchmarking to find out whether the exclude is really slowing you down. You could test whether the query with the `exclude` and slice is noticeably slower than the query just with the slice.

If you find that the exclude is slow, you could filter in Python

```
comments = [c for c in comments if c.submitter_id not in condemned].
```

Note that you may end up with fewer than 120 comments this way.

Another option is to add a `condemned` flag to the `Submitter` model, then change the query to `.exclude(submitter__condemned=True)`. This might be faster than the current `.exclude(submitter_id__in=condemned)`.

You should also check that your database has indexes for the `submitter_id` field. Since it's a foreign key, it probably does.